# Validation rule on lead conversion for new accounts only

Tags: validation-rule

What I am looking for is a way to run a validation rule and have it stop in its tracks if the Company type is not filled out on new lead conversion. here is what I have written so far

```
ISCHANGED(IsConverted)
&& IsConverted = TRUE
&& ISBLANK(TEXT( Company_Type__c))
&& ISPICKVAL(LeadSource, "Web")
```

However, if I am linking it to an already existing account, I do not want the validation rule to fire.

How do I accomplish this

Require Validation for Converted Leads is turned on

Comment: the validation rule has to run on the Account -- and you need to map three fields from the Lead to the Account : (1) some signal that Account was created by lead conversion; (2)  `leadsource` and (3) `company_type__c`

Comment: This worked thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the validation rule has to run on the Account -- and you need to map three fields from the Lead to the Account : (1) some signal that Account was created by lead conversion; (2) leadsource and (3) company_type__c – cropredy Dec 16 '20 at 1:49

Answer (score 0):

When a Lead Conversion occurs, the transaction scope includes:

- Creating or updating an Account
- Creating or updating a Contact
- Creating an Opportunity (optional)
- Updating the Lead to indicate it is converted and the related accountId, contactId, opportunityId

Thus, 4 DML operations occur in the transaction and if any of them fail, the conversion fails

So, in order to distinguish between new v existing Account, the validation rule has to run on Account and have enough information within the Account fields to differentiate between new v existing:

Map three fields from Lead to Account:

- Is_Created_By_Lead_Conversion__c (checkbox)
- Company_Type__c
- LeadSource__c

Then you can use Account Validation Rule

```
ISNEW()
&& Is_Created_By_Lead_Conversion__c
&& ISBLANK(TEXT( Company_Type__c))
&& ISPICKVAL(LeadSource__c, "Web")
```